# -[UIImage CGImage] returning nil

Tags: iphone, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics, cgimage

I'm wondering under which circumstances this code breaks in the **second** assert. In other words, when can `-[UIImage CGImage]` return `nil`? The documentation isn't very telling here.

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)anImage {
    assert(anImage);
    CGImageRef cgimage = anImage.CGImage;
    assert(cgimage);
}
```

I'm pretty sure, the UIImage is correct since it's fetched from the app bundle. So far I haven't been able to reproduce the case but I do see some user crash reports.

Comment: How are you getting the UIImage?

Comment: @Stephen, using `-[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possibility is that you have multiple threads accessing the same UIImage object at the same time; this was happening in my code with the same symptom.

That might explain your sporadic crash reports, too, since the access patterns would depend on timing that changes from run to run.

Answer (score 6):

One more possibility that I've come across in the docs:

> If the UIImage object was initialized using a CIImage object, the value of the property is NULL.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, if the first assert passes(showing that anImage is not nil) it means that it could not load the image.  Check to make sure that the image is being copied into your bundle.

Comment: It is in the bundle and it works in 99.9% of the cases. It only fails in the second assert under some rare circumstances I haven't been able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

A case where `anImage` would be non-nil but `cgimage` would be nil could be contrived as follows:

```
UIImage* myImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:nil];
```

As previous answers have indicated there are other ways one could find themselves in such a scenario.

Comment: You're right, but I'm using `-[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]` to create the image. So it's still a mystery to me. I've know worked around the issue by just ignoring the nil image instead of crashing in the assert.

Comment: And you're sure `pic.png` exists in your app's resources when everything is built? It is possible the image itself is missing there in which case the routine will return `nil`. Another possibility is that the image is somehow corrupted...

Comment: Totally sure it exists. It works in 99.9% of the cases, and I wasn't even able to reproduce the case where it fails. Just came across some crash reports where it fails in some cases. Notably, even for those crashing devices, the issue occurs randomly, only.